# SVN - is it possible to limit revision history for directories?

Tags: svn

coming from Perforce to SVN. Wondering if, like Perforce, there is a way to at the server level, set up certain subdirectories or files in a repository to only save X number of the most previous revisions?

While we would like the history of some files, like code, preserved indefinitely, there are some folders in the repository of large binaries, which are updated often. Their revision history is eating away at the server storage to an undesirable amount, and their history beyond a certain point is not really useful to us.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm almost sure it cannot be done. The general advice for versioning build binaries in SVN is "don't". Obliteration itself (e.g., removing any trace of unwanted data leaked into repository) is a manual admin task that basically means recreating the whole repository.

Comment: What makes you think Subversion would have such a feature?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález ah, oh well. These aren't build binaries, but art assets being submitted by team members for the software. I may have to then look into other ways of versioning this data

Comment: @Friedrich I didn't think that it did; I asked if it did, the impetus for such clearly described as the existence this feature in a competing product in the space